# Can I use ReadyBoost on Windows 10 with a USB Drive to increase the RAM available for usage in R

Tags: r, memory

R works in memory and Windows 10 provides a feature called ReadyBoost to increase the amount of working memory(well sort of).

By using ReadyBoost with an 8GB USB Drive and 8GB RAM on my laptop can I increase the total available RAM for R to say about 12-14 Gigs.

This would really help in running my queries

Comment: This is a SuperUser question

Comment: ReadyBoost does nothing with memory.  It stores files that are frequently loaded from disk.

Answer (score 0):

This is really more of a SuperUser question, but the answer is that it doesn't matter because R has a package which is made to switch data from in-memory to disk-based.

So, instead of trying to take advantage of ReadyBoost, which will very likely not work anyway, you can use the save flash drive memory or simply your hard disk drive memory to help scale your R session up via the package `ff`.

```
require(ff)
?ff
```

Comment: Can I run the algorithms from caret on ff. I understand that ff might not work with certain algorithms/ packages and hence a new package ffbase has also been written. However, this works for all functions in ffbase only i.e. it's not like data.table which works just like an extension of data frame

Comment: @ctd2015 As far as I know. I've never run into a limitation but it sounds like that the `ffbase` package overcomes whatever limitations there are. If you run into a problem that will make for a good StackOverflow question, so do post another question if you run into a specific limitation.